# Why does the factor of ⅔ come in when we calculate net flux due to diffusion for an ideal gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas, diffusion

As per Atkins' Physical Chemistry (11E) Pg:694. We arrive at a crude estimate for the net flux through an imaginary flux plane. We find it to be $$J_{z}=-\frac{1}{2}v_{mean}\lambda(\frac{d\mathcal{N}}{dz})_{z=0}$$ Where $v_{mean}$ is the *mean speed* of the ideal gas and $\lambda$ is the *mean free path*. Now according to Atkins, there should be a correction factor due to **Orientational Averaging** which comes out to be $2/3$. A small demonstration was also given in form of the figure below.
[image: Figure attempting to explain the correction]

I am trying to get more mathematical proof of why the factor of $2/3$ appears. If anyone can recommend to me how to approach it or suggest me any reading material where this thing is explained in detail please do help.